# Is it important to delete GPT/MBR labels before reformatting/repartitioning?

Tags: disk, gpt, mbr, partition-table

I've seen some disk formatting/partitioning discussions that mention destroying existing GPT/MBR data structures as a first step:

```bash
sgdisk --zap-all /dev/nvme0n1
```

I wasn't previously aware of this, and when I've set up a disk, I've generally used:

```bash
parted --script --align optimal  \
    /dev/nvme0n1 --              \
    mklabel gpt                  \
    mkpart ESP fat32 1MiB 512MiB \
    set 1 boot on                \
    name 1 boot                  \
    mkpart primary 512MiB 100%   \
    set 2 lvm on                 \
    name 2 primary
```

Should I have cleared things out (e.g. `sgdisk --zap-all`) first? What are the downsides to not having done that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This advice is from the time when other tools didn't properly support GPT and were not removing all the pieces of the GPT metadata. From `sgdisk` man page for the `--zap`/`--zap-all` option:

> Use this option if you want to repartition a GPT disk using fdisk or some other GPT-unaware program.

That's no longer true. Both `fdisk` and `parted` support GPT now and if you create a new partition table, they will remove both the two GPT headers (GPT has a backup header at the end of the disk that can cause problems when not removed) and the Protective MBR header.

That being said, it is generally not a bad idea to properly remove all headers/signatures when removing a preexisting storage layout. I personally use `wipefs` to remove signatures from all devices before removing them just to make sure there nothing left that could be unexpectedly discovered later -- I've been in situations where a newly created MD array or LVM logical volume suddenly has a filesystem on it just because it was created on the same (or close enough) offset where a previous device was. Storage tools usually try to detect filesystem signatures when creating a new partition/device and can wipe them for you, but doing that manually never hurts.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Using wipefs (`sudo wipefs --output TYPE,OFFSET /dev/nvme0n1`) to list the signatures on a machine I installed linux on, I see two gpt signatures and a PMBR signature. I thought there would be just one signature, gpt, so I'm wondering if the PMBR and one of the gpt signatures are residue from before I got my hands on this machine?

Comment: That's normal: One GPT signature at the beginning of the disk, one at the end of the disk (that's a backup copy of the first one) and PMBR for backwards compatibility with systems without GPT support (it's a simple MBR/DOS partition table with one "fake" partition spanning the entire disk -- systems that don't understand GPT will see that partition instead of "empty" disk).